# How to set the mainfest.xml to remove the default label

Tags: android

Any one can share the mainfest.xml.

How to set it? then can remove the label..?
Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but assuming you're asking about displaying the name of your application: There's a line in the < application > section that has "@string/app_name" in it, which you could remove. Not sure that's a good idea though. Alternatively you might be asking how to remove the title bar at the top of an application. If so, use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: I have use this method, But no use. really. I don't know why.
So i think may be can set it in the mainfest.xml,
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to show some code then. Edit your question, give a lot more detail - the command requestWindowFeature(...) does work, so either we're misunderstanding what you're asking or you're not using it properly.

Comment: +1 I have just used the requestWindowFeature(...) in my code and it works perfectly thanks for that, I was unaware of how to remove the title of the app

Answer (score 1):

If by removing the default label, you mean removing the title bar, you can use the following in your `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```